# How to return array from C++ function to Python using ctypes

Tags: c++, python, arrays, return, ctypes

I am using ctypes to implement a C++ function in Python. The C++ function should return a pointer to an array. Unfortunately I haven't figured out, how to access the array in Python. I tried numpy.frombuffer, but that was not successful. It just returned an array of arbitrary numbers. Obviously I didn't used it correctly. Here is a simple example with an array of size 10:

Content of function.cpp:

```
extern "C" int* function(){
int* information = new int[10];
for(int k=0;k<10;k++){
    information[k] = k;
}
return information;
}
```

Content of wrapper.py:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

output = ctypes.CDLL('./library.so').function()

ArrayType = ctypes.c_double*10
array_pointer = ctypes.cast(output, ctypes.POINTER(ArrayType))
print np.frombuffer(array_pointer.contents)
```

To compile the C++ file i am using:

```
g++ -c -fPIC function.cpp -o function.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,library.so -o library.so function.o
```

Do you have any suggestions what I have to do to access the array values in Python?

Comment: Of course i forgot to import some specific ctypes functions like c_double and POINTER. I just forgot to add them here.

Comment: LOOK AT THIS ANSWER : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74612547/9427260

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`function.cpp` returns an int array, while `wrapper.py` tries to interpret them as doubles. Change `ArrayType` to `ctypes.c_int * 10` and it should work.

---

It's probably easier to just use [`np.ctypeslib`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html) instead of `frombuffer` yourself. This should look something like

```
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./library.so')
lib.function.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, shape=(10,))

res = lib.function()
```

Comment: I imported also c_int and replaced c_double but python prints now an array of only 5 elements and the values are still wrong. This is weird.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! It works now. Python just gives me the warning "[...] RuntimeWarning: Invalid PEP 3118 format string: '<P' [...]" But according to [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964101/pep-3118-warning-when-using-ctypes-array-as-numpy-array) it is not a problem.

Comment: A bit of necromancery here... How would you delete the memory when done with it?

Comment: @XapaJlaMnu Your library should have a corresponding `extern C` function to call to free the memory, which internally uses C++ `delete` if it was allocated with `new`. ctypes uses C interfaces, and since C doesn't have `delete`, neither does ctypes.

Comment: As suggested in the other answer, if possible it's usually better to allocate the memory with numpy and pass it off to a C function to populate.

Comment: if we don't know the space needed in python and only know it after running in dll, how to do this? ...

Comment: look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74612547/9427260

Answer (score 28):

Your python code will work after some minor modifications:

```
import ctypes

f = ctypes.CDLL('./library.so').function
f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int * 10)
print [i for i in f().contents] # output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Basically there are two changes:

1. remove numpy-related code and `ctypes.cast` call since we don't need them.
2. specify the return type to `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int * 10)`.

   By default foreign functions are assumed to return the C int type, hence we need change it to the desired pointer type.

BTW, returning a `new`ed array from C code to Python code seems inappropriate. Who and when will free the memory? It's better to create arrays in Python code and pass them to C code. This way it's clear that the Python code **owns** the arrays and takes the responsibility of creating and reclaiming their spaces.

Comment: Can you point out how would we create such an array in python and pass it's pointer to C?

Comment: @Shahensha What I do for int/float arrays is use numpy arrays, and the embedded ctypes interface (`data_as`)

Comment: A bit of necromancery here... How would you delete the memory when done with it?

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu you could create a separate function to release the malloced memmory after you have safely returned and made a copy of the array in python

Comment: What to do if the size of the return array is unknown? f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int * what? )

Comment: Look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74612547/9427260