# How to return a matrix from a C++ function to Python using ctypes

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

I want to return a matrix from a C++ function to a Python function. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887378/how-to-return-array-from-c-function-to-python-using-ctypes) solution, which is an example for returning an array.

As a example, I want to return a `10x10` array filled of `10`'s.

**function.cpp:**

```
extern "C" int* function(){
int** information = new int*[10];
for(int k=0;k<10;k++) {
    information[k] = new int[10];
    }
for(int k=0;k<10;k++) {
    for(int l=0;l<10;l++) {
        information[k][l] = 10;
        }
}
return *information;
}
```

The Python code is:
**wrapper.py**

```
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./library.so')
lib.function.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, shape=(10,))

res = lib.function()
print res
```

For compiling this I use:

```
g++ -c -fPIC function.cpp -o function.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,library.so -o library.so function.o
```

If `soname` doesnt work, use `install_name`:

```
g++ -c -fPIC function.cpp -o function.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-install_name,library.so -o library.so function.o
```

After running the python program, `python wrapper.py` this is the output im having:
`[10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10]`

Only one row of 10 elements. I would like to have the 10x10 matrix. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887378/how-to-return-array-from-c-function-to-python-using-ctypes?lq=1

Comment: That one is for an array, this is for a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

`function.cpp`:

```
extern "C" int* function(){
    int* result = new int[100];
    for(int k=0;k<100;k++) {
        result[k] = 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In `wrapper.py`

```
lib.function.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, shape=(10,)) //incorrect shape
lib.function.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, ndim=2, shape=(10,10)) // Should be two-dimensional
```

Comment: Thanks. But that gives me the following error: `function.cpp:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘int**’ to ‘int’`

Comment: Wow. The output is giving me a super strange result. I've made a screenshot so you can see it. There are no 10's on the matrix, and I dont know what's happening: http://i.imgur.com/x5HDf0B.png

Comment: I think you might want to consider the following example: http://www.sagemath.org/doc/numerical_sage/ctypes_examples.html

Comment: There isn't an easiest way to return a matrix that rather than using `structs` and stuff?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not as good at ctypes to answer this question. The source of error is that by the time matrix is consumed by python wrapper memory is already freed and reused. Most likely array version have the same bug, but for some reason it's hidden. One more thing is that with that "simple" approach you have in mind if you manage to pass matrix outside of the function you won't be able to free the memory its consuming when you don't need it anymore. So I would suggest digging a little deeper into ctypes docs to find out how this situation is addressed.

Comment: I will wait and see if someone can give me another answer or something. Thanks John.

Comment: The NumPy array has to be C contiguous. Allocate and return `int *data = new int[10*10]`. Change the loop that initializes `information` to use `&data[10*k]`.

Comment: @eryksun Can you explain it a bit more in detail? Thanks.

Comment: @eryksun meant that an array must be allocated as one contiguous block in memory. To achieve that, it should be one-dimensional. Numpy than hides implementation details and provides convenient matrix-like interface. So, what you perceive as numpy matrix is actually represented by contiguous one-dimensional array in memory.

Comment: I really dont care if its `NumPy` or another `ctypes` function. So if there's another solution using other methods or other `ctypes`function, I'm open.

Comment: @Borja: An `int **` translates to ctypes `POINTER(POINTER(c_int))`. Then you can keep using your array of pointers. I don't know what the goal is, but I think if it's possible you should pass a ctypes or NumPy array (contiguous, row-major order) to the C++ function. That lets the Python caller manage the memory.

Comment: @eryksun The goal is just to write a matrix in the C++ code, and then send it on Python and save it under the name `res` so I can manipulate it.

Comment: @eryksun, I've tryed instead of the line using `lib.function.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_int, ndim=2, shape=(10,10))`use a double pointer as you said: `lib.function.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int *8))` but still doesnt work.

Comment: @Borja: Since you've allocated the non-contiguous arrays and array of pointers on the heap using C++, you'll have to add another function to free them when the Python caller no longer needs them. If you do the allocation in Python that gets handled automatically by object reference counting.

Comment: @Borja: Why are you using `c_int * 8`? It's just `POINTER(POINTER(c_int))`. Use it like `res[0][5]`, or creating a list of lists using `[r[:10] for r in res[:10]]`. You'll have to do manual bounds checking, i.e. for a 10x10 the following is out of bounds `res[0][10]`. That could result in a segfault/Windows exception.

Comment: `*8` was just because I put a smaller matrix so I can see it printed on a better way in the console. But well. it seems all this exceeds my C++/Python knowledge, which makes this impossible for me... I dont know how to free the memory when Python caller no longer needs them, among other a lot of things you are saying. I'll wait and see if someone can give me an answer and see if I can understand it then. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This is my last try, which prints a infinite list of numbers: `f = ctypes.CDLL('./library.so').function`, `f.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))` , `for i in f().contents: ` print i`

Comment: @Borja: If you're returning an `int **`, that's a pointer to an array of `int *` pointers. Each of those points at an `int` array. There's no bounds checking, so you can iterate it until you reach an unallocated address; then your OS will signal a segmentation fault (or Windows access violation). If you want bounds checking you could use `POINTER(POINTER(c_int * 10) * 10)`, but it's a bit cumbersome, e.g. creating a list of lists: `[r[0][:] for r in res[0][:]]`.

Comment: @J0HN Thanks, but that's not what I was asking on the question. In your answer you are not creating an matrix in `C++`, just a 100 values array and then make a size conversion (from `100` to `10x10`) when it arrives to `Python`. I want to have a matrix in `C++`, send it as a matrix to `Python`and manipulate it as a matrix.

Comment: Array is contiguous, i.e. it's colocated in memory, *as one chunk*. Matrix is sparse ("rows" of matrix are spread in memory space). `ctypes` does not work properly with sparse data. Looks like you'll have to do create auxiliary function to convert matrix to array.

Comment: @Borja: Just add `int **matrix = new int*[nrows];  for(int k=0; k<nrows; k++) { matrix[k] = &result[k * ncols]; }`. Remember to `delete matrix` and `return result`. However, I still think it's better to allocate the 2D array with NumPy and change the prototype to `function(int *array, int nrows, int ncols)`. @JOHN: The issue here is NumPy arrays have to be contiguous (default is row-major order like in C); it's not really a ctypes problem. You can easily use `POINTER(POINTER(c_int))` just like in C.