# Import C++ function in Python through ctypes: why segmentation fault?

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I tried to call this `C++` file (myfunc.cpp) from `Python`. I decided to use `ctypes` module, since it seems to work pretty well for both `C` and `C++` code.
I followed several tutorial (e.g., [Modern/2020 way to call C++ code from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084033/modern-2020-way-to-call-c-code-from-python)), which suggests to add '`extern C`' on the top of the `C++` function to be called in `Python`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int from_xy(int x, int y, int nside) {
    return x + (nside * y);
}

std::vector<int> to_xy(int k, int nside) {
    int x = k%nside;
    int y = floor(k / nside);
    vector<int> res(x, y);
    return res;
}

int modNegOperator(int k, int n){
    return ((k %= n) < 0) ? k+n : k;
}

extern "C"
double** create2Darray(unsigned nside,  double mx, double my) {

    int n_matrix = nside * nside;
    double **array2D = 0;
    array2D = new double *[n_matrix];

    for (int h = 0; h < n_matrix; h++) {
        array2D[h] = new double[n_matrix];

        for (int w = 0; w < n_matrix; w++) {
            // fill in some initial values
            // (filling in zeros would be more logic, but this is just for the example)
            array2D[h][w] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int h = 0; h < n_matrix; h++){

        std::vector<int> xy_vec = to_xy(h, nside);
        int modneg1 = modNegOperator(xy_vec[0] + 1,nside);
        int modneg2 = modNegOperator(xy_vec[0] - 1,nside);
        int modneg3 = modNegOperator(xy_vec[1] + 1,nside);
        int modneg4 = modNegOperator(xy_vec[1] - 1,nside);

        int pos1 = from_xy(modneg1, xy_vec[1], nside);
        int pos2 = from_xy(modneg2, xy_vec[1], nside);
        int pos3 = from_xy(xy_vec[0], modneg3, nside);
        int pos4 = from_xy(xy_vec[0], modneg4, nside);

        double half_mx = mx / 2;
        double half_my = my / 2;

        array2D[h][h] = 0;
        array2D[h][pos1] = half_mx;
        array2D[h][pos2] = half_mx;

        array2D[h][pos3] = half_my;
        array2D[h][pos4] = half_my;

    }

    return array2D;
}
```

I have then created a shared library:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -o libTest.so myfunc.cpp
```

Created a myLib.py file including:

```
import ctypes
import sys
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
handle = ctypes.CDLL(dir_path + "/libTest.so")

handle.create2Darray.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]

def create2Darray(nside, mx, my):
    return handle.create2Darray(nside, mx, my)
```

However, when I then try to run my function in python:

```
from myLib import *
create2Darray(4, 0.01,0.01)
```

I get 'Segmentation fault'.

Do you know what am I doing wrong? Do you have any suggestion? Or perhaps suggest another approach with which I can import my C++ function in python. The alternative ofcourse would be to re-write the code in C.

Comment: Use a debugger. If you're gonna hunt bugs in your c++ code you will need to learn how to use one. I can also recommend [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to get a more smooth way to talk to your c++ code. It even supports converting standard containers like `std::vector` and such to python objects.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider pybind11. However, I do not think there is a bug in my c++ code, since it runs smoothly.

Comment: runs smoothly? You mean when linking the library in C++ and calling the function?

Comment: Yes, when I just run my C++ code (without extern C, of course). In other words, the problem does not seem to be the C++ code itself.

Comment: Running in a debugger, your code is dereferencing a zero-length vector on line 42 `int modneg1 = modNegOperator(xy_vec[0] + 1,nside);` when `h = 0`.  There's nothing wrong with the `ctypes` code other than not defining `create2Darray.restype` and technically the first `.argtypes` should be `ctypes.c_uint`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. When I test the line 42 for h=0, I get 1 and not a zero-length vector. Also, I tried to add the corrections you suggested, but I still get 'Segmentation fault' and exit from python.

Comment: Undefined behavior.  `xy_vec.size()` is `0`.  Add `cout << xy_vec.size() << endl;` before the `int modneg1` line.

Comment: It gives me always 2. I never get 0. Btw, I think I understood the problem of 'Segmentation fault'. It is due to the fact that each element of the matrix I'm trying to build is allocated into memory. And according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113154/how-to-return-a-matrix-from-a-c-function-to-python-using-ctypes , there are no bounds checking, so you can iterate the filling of the matrix until you reach an unallocated address; then your OS will signal a segmentation fault. THE PROBLEM REMAINS ON HOW TO RETURN A 2D MATRIX FROM C++ INTO PYTHON.

Comment: @CafféSospeso The problem remains that you are refusing to face the fact that you have UB in your code.

Comment: @super, everything is alright. This comment is not very useful. Mark Tolonen was kind enough to discuss with me the solution.

Comment: @CafféSospeso Good that you got things sorted. I still find the comment highly relevant. It's very common to misunderstand what UB is or how it manifests... It was not meant to be rude or anything. Just informative.

Comment: No problem. With @MarkTolonen, we figured out that the problem is related to a mistake I made in the code I posted: res(x, y) instead of res{x, y}. However, your comment on pybind11 made me discover also an alternative solution to my initial problem. So, thanks to you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the chat we had, the code posted in the question segfaults because the following code returns a zero-length vector when first called:

```cpp
std::vector<int> to_xy(int k, int nside) {
    int x = k%nside;
    int y = floor(k / nside);
    vector<int> res(x, y);    // if k==0, this is length 0
    return res;
}
```

then this code faults here:

```cpp
    for (int h = 0; h < n_matrix; h++){

        std::vector<int> xy_vec = to_xy(h, nside);          // length 0
        int modneg1 = modNegOperator(xy_vec[0] + 1,nside);  // xy_vec[0] faults.
```

The code we discussed in chat didn't fail because:

```cpp
    vector<int> res(x, y);    // if k==0, this is length 0
```

had been changed to:

```cpp
    vector<int> res{x, y};    // curly braces, length 2
```

After resolving that, the Python code just needed `.restype` defined, and technically `c_uint` for the first parameter:

```py
handle.create2Darray.argtypes = ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double
handle.create2Darray.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
```

Then the code would return the `double**` correctly.