# Using Rust returned array in Python using ctypes

Tags: python, rust, ctypes

I have a Rust function that returns an `array` and I want to use this array in `Python`, it could be a `list` or `numpy.array` it does not really matter.

My Rust function looks like this:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn make_array() -> [i32; 4] {
    let my_array: [i32; 4] = [1,2,3,4];
    return my_array;
}
```

And I am trying to call it in Python like this:

```
In [20]: import ctypes

In [21]: from ctypes import cdll

In [22]: lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("/home/user/RustStuff/embed/target/release/libembed.so")

In [23]: lib.make_array.restype = ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_int32, 4)

In [24]: temp = lib.make_array()

In [25]: [i for i in temp]
Out[25]: [1, 2, -760202930, 32611]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my output not `[1,2,3,4]`? Why are my first two elements right and other two are populated with garbage?

I was not able to find any good documentation on `ctypes.ARRAY`, so I just went with what looked right, so that is likely the problem.

Comment: A minor style nit, but your Rust function could be `pub extern fn make_array() -> [i32; 4] { [1,2,3,4] }`.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I see thank you. I do need to get used to proper `rust` style.

Comment: I don't know how Rust's ABI handles returning fixed-sized arrays but AFAIK C can't do that so I wouldn't expect ctypes, or any C ABI-consumer, to be able to work with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have said, you can't *really* return a fixed-size array properly.  But you can *trick* ctypes into doing the right thing by wrapping the array in a structure:

```
import ctypes

class Int32_4(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("array", ctypes.c_int32 * 4)]

lib = ctypes.CDLL("embed.dll")
lib.make_array.restype = Int32_4

temp = lib.make_array()

print(temp.array[:])
```

This results in `[1, 2, 3, 4]` on my machine.

**Addendum**: This is a "trick" because we're exploiting a difference between what C can do and what Rust can do.  C *won't* let you return a fixed-sized array by value, but Rust *will*, and it works the same as returning a user-defined structure.

So, we do something that C *will* allow: returning a structure which happens to contain a fixed-size array.  This, it is fine with, and it matches the layout that Rust is using.

Of course, this is also somewhat hacky, in that I'm not *entirely* convinced that this is well-defined behaviour.  If you want to be extra safe, you could change the return type on the Rust side to match C:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Int32_4 {
    array: [i32; 4]
}
```

Comment: Nice, but can you explain how your solution works. For example, I don't understand why this is a "trick" as opposed to normal usage of `ctypes`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thank You.

Comment: @DK.: The in-memory layout will match because the C Standard requires that the address of a `struct` and the address of its first data member match (ie, no front padding); it might be running afoul of the strict aliasing rules, but across languages it should not matter. Nonetheless, it is better to wrap in `struct` on both ends, it will lead to less head-scratching on the part of future maintainers.

Comment: @MatthieuM. When I said I wasn't convinced it was well-defined behaviour, I meant on the Rust side of things.  Sure, returning an array by value as if it were a struct makes *sense*, but it's not as though changing it would break integration with C code; C *can't* return arrays by value, so surely no one is depending on the exact behaviour!  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what [@delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789765/using-rust-returned-array-in-python-using-ctypes#comment49629297_30789765) said - [you can't return fixed-size arrays in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11656585/155423). One main incompatibility is that Rust arrays know what size they are, but C arrays do not. You will need to abide by how every other C program has done this - return a pointer and a length separately. Isn't Rust a nice modern language in comparison?

I stole and modified some Python code [from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892980/155423)

```python
import ctypes

from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("libarray.dylib")
lib.make_array.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32 * 4)

print [i for i in lib.make_array().contents]
```

This works with this Rust code:

```rust
static ARRAY: [i32; 4] = [1,2,3,4];

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn make_array() -> *const i32 {
    ARRAY.as_ptr()
}
```

Here, we are doing the simplest thing, creating an array that will live for the entire length of the program and returning a reference to its data. In your real program, you will likely need to take more care to ensure that your `Vec<i32>` or `&[i32]` strictly outlives how long the Python code has the pointer, else you will cause memory corruption.

Comment: Given my result, it seems that the pointer to first element is actually getting passed though, since the first two elements are right, and it is the length that is off!

Comment: @Akavall I have no idea what the memory layout of a Rust array is, so it's hard to guess what's happening. Some of those numbers might be padding bytes that are uninitialized. It's possible that the size of the array is any size from `u8` to `u64` (or possibly `usize`), so it's not easy to decode what memory it is you are printing.