# Rust function called using ctypes only returns first value

Tags: python, rust, ctypes

I have a rust function that looks like so:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn convert(inp_a: f32, inp_b: f32) -> (i32, i32) {
    // some things happen
    return (res_a, res_b)
}
```

This works as expected.

However, if I attempt to call it from Python, like so:

```
from ctypes import cdll, c_float
from sys import platform

if platform == "darwin":
    ext = "dylib"
else:
    ext = "so"

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('target/debug/foreign.' + ext)
convert = lib.convert

a = -0.32824866
b = 51.44533267
print convert(c_float(a), c_float(b))
```

I only get the first half of the result back, as an `int`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789765/using-rust-returned-array-in-python-using-ctypes

Comment: Yep, that works. Can you post it as an answer?