# Passing C++ double array to Python Results in a Crash

Tags: python, c++, arrays

I'm running into an issue while trying to pass a double array from C++ to Python.  I run a script to create a binary file with data, then read that data back into an array and am trying to pass the array to Python.  I've followed advice here: [how to return array from c function to python using ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887378/how-to-return-array-from-c-function-to-python-using-ctypes) among other pages I have found through google.  I can write a generic example that works fine (like a similar array to the link above), but when I try to pass the array read from a binary file (code below), the program crashes with "Unhandled exception at ADDR (ucrtbase.dll) in python.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."  So, I'm wondering if anyone has any insight.

A word on methodology:

Right now, I'm just trying to learn - that's why  I'm going through the convoluted process of saving to disk, loading, and passing to Python.  Eventaully, I will use this in scientific simulations where the data read from disk needs to be generated by distributed computing/a super computer.  I would like to use Python for its ease of plotting (matplotlib) and C++ for its speed (iterative calculations, etc).

So, on to my code.  This generates the binary file:

```
for (int zzz = 0; zzz < arraysize; ++zzz)
{
    for (int yyy = 0; yyy < arraysize; ++yyy)
    {
        for (int xxx = 0; xxx < arraysize; ++xxx)
        {//totalBatP returns a 3 element std::vector<double> - dblArray3_t is basically that with a few overloaded operators (+,-,etc)
            dblArray3_t BatP = B.totalBatP({ -5 + xxx * stepsize, -5 + yyy * stepsize, -5 + zzz * stepsize }, 37);
            for (int bbb = 0; bbb < 3; ++bbb)
            {
                dataarray[loopind] = BatP[bbb];
                ++loopind;
                ...(end braces here)
FILE* binfile;
binfile = fopen("MBdata.bin", "wb");
fwrite(dataarray, 8, 3 * arraysize * arraysize * arraysize, binfile);
```

The code that reads the file:

```
DLLEXPORT double* readDblBin(const std::string filename, unsigned int numOfDblsToRead)
{
    char* buffer = new char[numOfDblsToRead];
    std::ifstream binFile;
    binFile.open(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    binFile.read(buffer, numOfDblsToRead);
    double* dataArray = (double*)buffer;
    binFile.close();

    return dataArray;
}
```

And the Python Code that receives the array:

```
def readBDataWrapper(filename, numDblsToRead):
    fileIO = ctypes.CDLL('./fileIO.dll')
    fileIO.readDblBin.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_uint)
    fileIO.readDblBin.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)

    return fileIO.readDblBin(filename, numDblsToRead)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - at least it appears to be working.  The problem was with the binary files that were generated with the first code block.  I swapped the c-style writing with ofstream.  My assumption is perhaps I was using the code to write to disk wrong somehow.  Anyway, it appears to work now.

Replaced:

```
FILE* binfile;
binfile = fopen("MBdata.bin", "wb");
fwrite(dataarray, 8, 3 * arraysize * arraysize * arraysize, binfile);
```

With:

```
std::ofstream binfile;
binfile.open("MBdata.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
binfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dataarray), std::streamsize(totaliter * sizeof(double)));
binfile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is here

```
char* buffer = new char[numOfDblsToRead];
```

Here you allocate `numOfDblsToRead` ***bytes***. You probably want `numOfDblsToRead * sizeof(double)`.

Same with the reading from the file, you only read `numOfDblsToRead` *bytes*.

Comment: Interesting.  So, I'm assuming this only applies to char arrays?  If I specify a double array and give it a number of elements, that should create enough room, right?

Comment: You bring up a good point; however, it still is not working.  Any other ideas?