# Passing std:vector from C++ to Python via Ctypes: getting nonsensical values

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I was trying to follow the [procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887649/8408902) here but I'm stuck. I'm trying to pass an `std:vector` from my C++ code (wrapped in `extern C`) to Python. This is what I have:

```
extern 'C' {
    double* returnQ() {
        std::vector<double> v = {7.5, 5.5, 16.5, 8.5};
        std::cout<<"Print first element:"<<vec[0]<<std::endl;
        return v.data(); }
}
```

This is my python code. After loading the library via `ctypes` as `lib`, I have:

```
def q():
    lib.returnQ.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_double, shape=(4,))
    return lib.returnQ()
```

However, when I call `q()` in Python, I get an array of random numbers. I'm not sure why?

Comment: It's `restype`, not `restypes`, and also you're returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: Why is that dangling? I never deleted `vec`

Comment: @tryingtosolve vector goes away when it's scope goes away - i.e. the end of the function - and with it, all the data it was holding.  Also, your code doesn't compile, so it's hard to make sense of what you're saying.  Are `v` and `vec` the same thing?

Comment: @xaxxon What can I do then? Store that in a native c++ array?

Comment: @tryingtosolve no, that would go away too.   Lexical scoping is pretty fundamental in all languages.. so it seems like you're pretty far over your head here.  Whatever you do, the vector (or array or whatever) you're returning a pointer into has to live past the end of the function.

Comment: @xaxxon Why did the post that I'm linking to work? It was returning an array as well?

Comment: @tryingtosolve because it "leaks" the memory from the call to new.  Heap allocations persist until they are programmatically cleaned up - they are not lexically scoped.  "leaks" in quotes because I'm not sure if it's somehow managed elsewhere.. but it's considered to be poor form to return un-managed heap memory that is allocated in a function.

Comment: @xaxxon just fixed my code such that it compiles. What's a viable solution? Thank you.

Comment: @tryingtosolve the correct way to write the code is situational and there's not enough context in your question for me to provide a suggestion.

Comment: @xaxxon I cannot, since the entire code is too long. I wrapped a class `car` written in C++ via ctypes. This class `car` contains an `std::vector` and I have a function that modifies this vector. In Python, after creating an instance of this class, I will call the function to modify the vector. Afterwards, I want to access the vector.

Comment: Just forget about Python (temporarily). Pretend your own C++ code needs to use v.data(). But you cannot place v in the same function that needs it. How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your vector is a local variable and destroyed after return from the function.  One way that works is to let Python manage the memory and copy the data into it.

**test.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

#define API __declspec(dllexport) // Windows-specific export

// Must pass double[4] array...
extern "C" API void returnQ(double* data) {
    std::vector<double> v = {7.5, 5.5, 16.5, 8.5};
    // Of course, you could write directly to "data" without the vector...
    std::memcpy(data,v.data(),v.size() * sizeof v[0]);
}
```

Usage:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> dll = CDLL('test')
>>> dll.returnQ.argtypes = POINTER(c_double),
>>> dll.returnQ.restype = None
>>> data = (c_double * 4)()  # equivalent to C++ double[4]
>>> dll.returnQ(data)
>>> list(data)
[7.5, 5.5, 16.5, 8.5]
```