# calling c++ functions in python: undefined symbol: TF_DeleteTensor

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, ctypes, cppflow

I want to do inference of a python classification model (tensorflow framework) in c++ (in order to increase speed). I succeeded to do that using [cppflow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow). The next step is to call the inference c++ function in python in order to use it in my application.
Here is the c++ script **predict.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cppflow/cppflow.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;


extern "C" cppflow::tensor predict(string model_path, string img_path) {

    cppflow::model model(model_path);
    auto input = cppflow::decode_jpeg(cppflow::read_file(string(img_path)));
    
    input = cppflow::cast(input, TF_UINT8, TF_FLOAT);
    input = cppflow::expand_dims(input, 0);
    
    auto output = model({{"serving_default_input_2:0", input}},{"StatefulPartitionedCall:0"});
    
    auto res = output[0];
    return res;

}
```

I followed [this site](https://www.journaldev.com/31907/calling-c-functions-from-python) in order to call the *"predict"* function in python, I constructed *"predict.so"* using the following command line:
`g++ -I../cppflow/include/ -fPIC -shared -o predict.so predict.cpp`
Then I wrote the following python script:

```
from ctypes import *
model_path = 'xxx'
image_path = 'yyy'
so_file = "./predict.so"
my_functions = CDLL(so_file)
result = my_functions.predict(model_path, image_path)
```

However, I got the following error when running *"my_functions = CDLL(so_file)"*:

```
OSError: undefined symbol: TF_DeleteTensor
```

Anybody knows why?
I also tried to use [boost library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html), but I didn't manage to run it properly. If you can show me how to use it properly I would be very grateful.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: `ctypes` ("C" types) only understands simple C data types and structure.  It has no support for `std::string` parameters or classes such as `cppflow::tensor` as a return value, although you could return a `cppflow::tensor*` and treat is a an opaque value that can be passed to other C functions that take that type of pointer.  If you can export an `extern "C" function that wraps the C++ function and sticks to types `ctypes` supports, it can work.

Comment: Thank you @MarkTolonen ! When u said "It has no support for std::string parameters or classes such as cppflow::tensor as a return value", did u mean that only input and output types should be ctypes, or all types (including local variables) used in my function should be ctypes? Otherwise have you another idea how to use c++ in python ctypes?

Comment: The interface (i/o) must be C. You can use anything in the implementation.

Comment: Simple example [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881136/235698)

Comment: I tried many things but I keep getting this error "undefined symbol: TF_DeleteTensor" due to cppflow. The error is in this line of code 'cppflow::model model(model_path);'. Could you please tell how to succeed cdll in my specific case? thanks

Comment: Sounds like a linker error. Are you trying to compile the code? We are not mind readers. Post enough information to reproduce the issue.