# How does python receive C++ arrays

Tags: python, ctypes

```py
from ctypes import *

# U Disk information
class DiskInfo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("total_space", c_long), ("free_space", c_long), ("used_space", c_long), ("user_name", c_char*20)]

class ManyDiskInfo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("disk_array", DiskInfo * 2)]
    
# Create Instance
obj_di = DiskInfo()
obj_mdi = ManyDiskInfo()

#load
dll = windll.LoadLibrary("FlashSpeedSta.dll")
disk_path = c_char_p(b"G:\\")

# Return singl disk information
dll.GetDiskSpace.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(DiskInfo)]
dll.GetDiskSpace.restype = POINTER(DiskInfo)
result = dll.GetDiskSpace(disk_path, buref(obj_di))
print(obj_di, obj_di.total_space, obj_di.used_space, obj_di.user_name)

#Returns multiple disk information
dll.GetDiskSpaceed.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(ManyDiskInfo)]
dll.GetDiskSpaceed.restype = POINTER(ManyDiskInfo)
dll.GetDiskSpaced(disk_path, byref(obj_mdi))
for n in obj_mid_disk.array:
    print(n, n.total_space, n.free_space, n.used_space, n.user_name)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.DiskInfo object at 0x019AFCB0> 2918 2918 0 b'TW2981'
<__main__.DiskInfo object at 0x019AFE90> 0 0 71567872 b'@\nD\x04@\nD\x04'
<__main__.DiskInfo object at 0x019AFEE0> 0 0 b''
```

Python returns a single disk and can run, but fails to return multiple disks. Why? Our C++ colleagues use Vector Pointers

[image]

Comment: Please add your code example as text.

Comment: Python *and* C code.  Note this is `ctypes` not `c++types`.  The interface has to be *C* types.  You can use a vector internally, but the I/O parameters must be C-compatible and the function must be declared `extern "C"`.

Comment: Here's a probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881136/235698.  Note that for variable data, both a pointer and size should be passed and/or returned, but that example expects a fixed sized return.